# Export from datagridview to *.txt file only first 20 cell's letters

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to export from datagridview to *.txt file

```
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt");       
int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{
sw.Write("{0,-20}", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());       
}                
sw.Close();
```

But if my datagridview's cell is bigger than `20 letters` i want to delete rest of them. And to export only my first 20 letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you in following way: include the snippet inside the `for`

```
string tempString = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
if(tempString.Length>20)
   tempString=tempString.Substring(0,20);
else
   {
     tempString = tempString.PadRight(20); //use this if you need space after the word
            tempString = tempString.PadLeft(20); //use this if you need space before the word
   }
sw.Write(tempString);
```

Update: as per op's comment:

You can use [Padding](http://www.dotnetperls.com/padright) to append an empty string with your actual string. C# offers two padding options such as right padding and left padding.

> PadRight adds spaces to the right of strings. PadLeft meanwhile adds
>   to the left. These methods make the text easier to read. Padding a string
>   adds whitespace or other characters to the beginning or end. Any
>   character can be used for padding.

Comment: Thank you sir it works.But what if my word is smaller and i want to add spaces till  i fill 20letters."{0,-20}"?

Comment: What you need is formatting, you can do this using `String.Format("{0,-20}", tempString);`

Comment: Please take a look into the updates in my answer. that may help you